# Memory leak in third party library in R

Tags: r, memory-leaks

I am currently doing a simulation experiment in `R` using a third party package (the package is `iRF` but in principle it doesn't matter what the package is) which appears to have a memory leak. A small example reproducing the problem is:

```
library(zeallot)
library(iRF)

simulate_data <- function() {
  X <- matrix(runif(300 * 50), nrow = 300)
  Y <- X[,1] + X[,2] + rnorm(nrow(X))
  return(list(X = X, Y = Y))
}

for(i in 1:10) {
  c(X, Y) %<-% simulate_data()
  fit <- iRF(X, Y)
  rm(fit)
  gc()
}
```

This uses just over 1Gb of ram. The package in question makes use of compiled `C` code, and presumably the memory leak is occuring there; hence, I cannot straight-forwardly free the memory in `R`. The question is: *is there any way to get around this memory leak without restarting my R session?* I'm not sure if this makes sense (I'm an ignorant statistician) but is there some way to nuke everything in the `C` world as though I reset the session? It is extremely inconvenient that if I want to replicate the experiment 1000 times I will have to reboot `R` or run out of memory.

Comment: Ultimately, I don't think you'll be able to harness that much control over R's memory management. Your best bet is to use some parallelization scheme with data/object-passing to calculate a portion of what you need, pass to the parent R session, then exit.

Comment: you should [email the maintainer](https://github.com/sumbose/iRF/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L25) or log an [issue/pull request](https://github.com/sumbose/iRF/issues)

Comment: @r2evans That works perfectly, thanks! If you want to convert that to an answer, I'll accept it unless somebody gives a much better answer within a few days.

Comment: @rawr Right, I intend to, but I'm more interested in a general solution that is not contingent upon the maintainer doing something.

Comment: @MrFlick I removed the edit, I will add it as an answer in a bit but wanted to give others an opportunity to answer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot fix the source, then your only option is to contain the problem. If the calculations can be broken into smaller components, you have a few options

1. calculate what you can, save into `.rda` files, restart R, continue; or
2. use a parallelization scheme such as `future` or `parallel::parLapplyLB` to farm out the processing into subordinate R sessions, capture the output, and allow the child processes to close.

Answer (score 1):

Following @r2evans advice, the issue can be bypassed through the use of `parallel`. The following code does not suffer from the memory leak:

```
library(zeallot)
library(iRF)
library(parallel)

simulate_data <- function() {
  X <- matrix(runif(300 * 50), nrow = 300)
  Y <- X[,1] + X[,2] + rnorm(nrow(X))
  return(list(X = X, Y = Y))
}

f <- function(i) {
  c(X, Y) %<-% simulate_data()
  return(iRF(X, Y))
}

for(i in 1:10) {
  cl <- makeCluster(1, "FORK")
  fit <- clusterApply(cl, 1, f)[[1]]
  stopCluster(cl)
}
```

Comment: I just larned about `zeallot`, interesting. Too bad, though, that the `%<-%` operator is popular, now I have to choose between `zeallot` and [`future`](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future) (esp since I think it looks reasonable in both).